# After panning an image in a picture box, how to save only the visible image

Tags: c#, image, graphics, picturebox

I have a C# program where I am displaying a pictureBox of size
600x450. I have an image of a higher resolution that I am displaying
in this window. After I pan the image, I want to save only the visible
picture in the window. When I use `pictureBox.Image.Save(...)`, it saves
the whole picture, not just the visual portion? How can I do this?

Comment: You can use [Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to crop image to visible size.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use this.

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(YourPictureBox.ClientSize.Width,
                               YourPictureBox.ClientSize.Height))
{
   YourPictureBox.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, YourPictureBox.ClientRectangle);
   bitmap.Save(yourfilename, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: As a follow up, if I pan the image in the pictureBox and then use the above code, it saves the whole image. If I don't pan but only zoom in, it works. TY.